# Is there any topology handler in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, topology

When importing autocad maps, sometimes topology will be chaos, this need to be amended.
And when I add new topology in QGIS, how to save that to the postgreSQL?
Is these functions included in QGIS or secondary development will be needed?

Answer (score 1):

Look for "Topology Checker" plugin and "Processing LWGEOM Provider" plugin that add postgis MakeValid command to Processing Toolbox.

there are other gis.stackexchange messages related with these two plugins.

regards,